# Python: how to split a sequence of text

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have a string:

```
st = "( hey + there )"
```

and I want to get a list containing these elements:

```
['(', 'hey', '+', 'there', ')']
```

I know I can do `st.split(" ")`, but that would not work whenever I have:

```
st = "(hey + there)"
```

it would return:

```
['(hey', '+', 'there)']
```

I am using Python 2.6

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem.

```
import re
line = "(hey + there)"
matchObj = re.match( r'^(\()\s*(\w+)\s(\+)\s(\w+)\s*(\))', line)
print(matchObj.groups())
```